# what does .erase() and .size() do in this code?

Tags: c++, file-handling

In the following code what these function does, particularly what does .erase do?

`ofstream output((filename.erase(filename.size()-4)).c_str(),ios::binary);`

Comment: add to your code `auto a = filename.erase(filename.size()-4)` and see the value of `a` in the debugger.

Comment: [Documentation for `std::string::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase)

Comment: Thanks, @user4581301 I got it. It is actually creating a new file whose name has a length less than 'filename' name length i.e if filename="data.txt.huf" then file it creates has name="data.txt".